# Java crm set values for field type Two Option

Tags: java, soap, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I want to set a field in mscrm whose data type is Two Option, for pick list data type i used `OrganizationServiceStub.OptionSetValue` but the same cannot be used for Two Option data types. I am using the stub does anyone know how to set value for such field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Two Option field, simply set it to true or false. Regardless of how you label them, the option with value 1 will be true and 0 will be false.

Comment: ya but i need to use one of the methods from the stub to set the two option field, `OrganizationServiceStub.OptionSetValue`  works for Option Set datatype fields only not for Two Option

Comment: Just use true or false. You don't need to use the OptionSet type for two OptionSet fields. They are just a bit field behind the scenes.